# Java Deque algorithm

Tags: java, deque, arraydeque

I'm fairly new to Java and learning Dequeue at the moment.

I have a pretty easy task, but I'm doing something wrong and would love some help on this specific task and also some tips on how to approach those kind of tasks.

I am given 2 Deques:
charDeque  = [a, e, i , o , u, b] (a is head b is tail)
intDeque = [3, 6, 9] (3 is head 9 is tail).

I'm required to set an output of integers and characters from that from top to bottom should look like this : [3, a, 6, e, 9, i, o, u, b] //top to bottom.

Here's my code. My approach is to loop over the two Deques and get the tail with the pollLast(); method and push it to an empty Deque - mergedStack. However, my output is close but not quite there : [o, 9, u, 6, b, 3]. I assuming I have a problem with the while loop, can anyone assist ?

```java
package QueueInterfaceExercise1;

import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Deque;

public class Tester {

    public static Deque<Object> mergeQueue(Deque<Integer> intQueue, Deque<Character> charQueue) {
        //Implement your logic here and change the return statement accordingly 
//      System.out.println(intQueue);
    System.out.println(charQueue);
//      [3, 6, 9]
//      [a, e, i, o, u, b]
        Deque<Object> mergedStack = new ArrayDeque<Object>();
//      Object number = intQueue.getLast();
//      System.out.println(number);
//      mergedStack.addLast(number);
        
        while( !intQueue.isEmpty() && !charQueue.isEmpty() ) {
            int number = intQueue.pollLast();
            char letter = charQueue.pollLast();
            mergedStack.push(number);
            mergedStack.push(letter);
        }
        return mergedStack;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Deque<Integer> integerQueue = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
        integerQueue.add(3);
        integerQueue.add(6);
        integerQueue.add(9);
        
        Deque<Character> characterQueue = new ArrayDeque<Character>();
        characterQueue.add('a');
        characterQueue.add('e');
        characterQueue.add('i');
        characterQueue.add('o');
        characterQueue.add('u');
        characterQueue.add('b');
        
        Deque<Object> mergedQueue = mergeQueue(integerQueue, characterQueue);
        
        System.out.println("The elements in the merged queue are:");
        for(Object element: mergedQueue)
            System.out.println(element);
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is close. Basically, you want to keep consuming elements from either deque while either deque has elements. So you want an `or` (not an `and`). Something like,

```
public static Deque<Object> mergeQueue(Deque<Integer> intQueue, 
        Deque<Character> charQueue) {
    Deque<Object> mergedStack = new ArrayDeque<>();
    while (!intQueue.isEmpty() || !charQueue.isEmpty()) {
        if (!intQueue.isEmpty()) {
            mergedStack.push(intQueue.pop());
        }
        if (!charQueue.isEmpty()) {
            mergedStack.push(charQueue.pop());
        }
    }
    return mergedStack;
}
```